# Airflow experimental API call method not allowed

Tags: rest, airflow, rbac

I am using Airflow v1.10.2 and referring to [experimental REST API documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html). When I try to make API calls for

`GET /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs`  or

`POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs`

I get 405 error. Specifically the response of the API call is,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Somewhere I read that RBAC UI has to be enabled but I am totally unaware about this. Would request Airflow masters here to suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug in `1.10.2` and will be fixed in `1.10.3` which will be released this week.

Till then you can fix it using the following:

Enable the RBAC UI by modifying `airflow.cfg` file.

Under `[webserver]` section, change `rbac = False` to `rbac = True`

Note you will have to create a user as per https://airflow.apache.org/security.html?highlight=rbac#password